# How to generate a random string in Java program

Tags: java, random

Here is my attempted code for this homework problem:

Write a method called randomLines that prints between 5 and 10 random strings of letters (between "a" and "z"), one per line. Each string should have random length of up to 80 characters.

public static void randomLines () {

```
Random rand = new Random();


for (int i = 1; i<=rand.nextInt(6)+5; i++) {

    for(int j = 1; j <= rand.nextInt(25)+97; j++){


           System.out.print(s.charAt(r.nextInt(N)));           
           System.out.println((char) rand.nextInt(25)+97);

    }
}
```

}

Here is my only question:

How can I get a random Character to print here:

```
System.out.println((char) rand.nextInt(25)+97); << prints random integers not characters
```

My logic is this: ASCII characters for that range are between 97-122 (a-z).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: did you do research before ask? please google search 'java generate random string site:stackoverflow.com'

Comment: Yes, I did search and my question was very specific about a single line I had. Nothing matched exactly what I was looking for, but the answer below was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the track, you just need to watch your order of operations. [Typecasting comes before addition](http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php), since it is unary. Just add some parenthesis!

```
System.out.println((char) (rand.nextInt(25)+97));
```

Comment: First one in with the exact thing I needed. I realize there were other issues in the code, but this line is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toString%28char%29) to convert it to a character. 
System.out.println(Char.toString(rand.nextInt(25)+97));

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
System.out.prinln(Char.toString(rand.nextInt(25)+97);
```